# Rails - Read HTML fragment from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i need a way to select a fragment of HTML FROM a rails VIEW.

The method i need is exactly the same as the ActionDispatch::Assertions::SelectorAssertions::css_select method, but i need it into the VIEW layer.

I found the HTML::Selector class, but cannot make it functions as i want.

Any ideas?
Best regards,
Mike

Comment: OK, i've resolved my issue by partializing the HTML fragment and reading it as a "render :partial...". Anyway i am curious about including the css_select method directly in the CONTROLLER/VIEW layers. So, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be way more messy than it needs to be, but in your class:

```
require 'action_dispatch/testing/assertions'
require 'action_dispatch/testing/assertions/selector'
include ActionDispatch::Assertions::SelectorAssertion
require 'action_controller/vendor/html-scanner/html/tokenizer'
require 'action_controller/vendor/html-scanner/html/document'
```

With this in place, you can parse your `@raw` HTML thus:

```
@selected = HTML::Document.new(@raw).root.children
```

With `@selected` set, you can call `css_selected`.

Note: with Rails 2.x, replace the first three lines with:

```
require 'action_controller/assertions/selector_assertions'
include ActionController::Assertions::SelectorAssertions
```

You can find a working example of this at https://github.com/rubys/gorp/blob/master/lib/gorp/test.rb